# Loop through all jbake configuration options

Tags: jbake, jbake-templates

Is there any way to loop through all jbake configuration options? I know that you can do config.[option] for single options. But is there a way to get all of them?

Comment: What template engine do you want to do this in?

Comment: in the gsp template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to loop through all the config options:

```
<%
config.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}<br>"}
%>
```